# How to invoke some method during the initialising process of an instance in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to Python,

After initialising an instance `f` of class `Fraction`, I want the method `reduce` has been invoked, so the `print` result is after reduced

```
f = Fraction(3,6)

print f #=> 1/2 not 3/6
```

here's the code:

```
class Fraction(object):
    '''Define a fraction type'''
    def __init__(self, num=0, denom=1):
        '''Create a new Fraction with numerator num and denominator demon'''
        self.numerator = num
        if denom != 0:
            self.denominator = denom
        else:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
    def reduce(self):
        gcd = findgcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator /= gcd
        self.denominator /= gcd

    def findgcd(self, x, y):
        gcd = None
        min_number = min(x, y)
        for i in range(min_number, 1, -1):
            if x % i == 0 and y % i == 0:
                gcd = i
        return gcd

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}/{1}".format(self.numerator, self.denominator)
```

Comment: I may be confused, but sounds like you just want to call self.reduce() at the end of your \_\_init\_\_ method?

Comment: `from fractions import Fraction`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. you need to call `self.reduce()` in your constructor `__init__` to have method `reduce()` invoked during the instantiation phase.
2. you also need to change:

   ```
   def reduce(self):
       gcd = findgcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
   ```

   to:

   ```
   def reduce(self):
       gcd = self.findgcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
   ```

because otherwise your instance will not be able to find `findgcd`.

---

The following code will fix your problem:

```
class Fraction(object):
    '''Define a fraction type'''
    def __init__(self, num=0, denom=1):
        '''Create a new Fraction with numerator num and denominator demon'''
        self.numerator = num
        if denom != 0:
            self.denominator = denom
        else:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
        self.reduce()

    def reduce(self):
        gcd = self.findgcd(self.numerator, self.denominator)
        self.numerator /= gcd
        self.denominator /= gcd

    def findgcd(self, x, y):
        gcd = None
        min_number = min(x, y)
        for i in range(min_number, 1, -1):
            if x % i == 0 and y % i == 0:
                gcd = i
        return gcd

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0}/{1}".format(self.numerator, self.denominator)

>>>> f = Fraction(3,6)
>>>> f
1/2
```

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, and +1 form point the other mistake of `self.gcd`. BTW we have the same last name. Are you a Chinese Kay?

Comment: @yozloy Glad to help! (yes :) Chinese-Canadian to be precise)

Comment: Great! and WOW !`Man on Wire` also my favourite! I've followed you on twitter

Comment: @yozloy Great to find someone like this film on SO :)

Answer (score 2):

What prevent you from calling `self.reduce()` at the end of `__init__` method?

Comment: +1 for the simple answer, It's works, I know what I was thinking back then, thanks